# Default.png images and iPad

Tags: ipad, orientation

I'm about to submit my first iPad app, and I have 2 questions regarding to Default.png images.

1. I would prefer a "splash screen" showing some artwork of my app, instead of the UI as if it was loaded, the app is a bit heavy and I've seen the users dispair when the UI is apparently loaded but it's not working. **Does anyone know if apple is accepting apps with "splash screens"?**
2. I want to provide a Default-X.png for every orientation, I've read the iPad programming guide, my question is, **is "Default-LandscapeLeft" a Default image rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and "Default-LandscapeRight" rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise?**

I'm asking this because I don't have an iPad yet to test this on.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Some are accepted, some are not, it doesn't all depend on that. However, it is recommended that you avoid the heavy loading times that would require a splash-screen. You could find a compromise by showing an image of a faded-out version of your working UI. If you need initial loading activity, consider deferring this loading stage after the Default.png is displayed, and use a view with similar aspect, but with some sort of progress indicator.
2. You don't need an iPad to test it, you can use the simulator, it can be rotated.

Comment: It is best to always have a splash screen instead of a black screen during even the initial minimal loading time. What type of splash screen, I won't go into that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the App Store, most apps use a splash screen rather than a UI capture, despite what the UI guidelines say.

And you are correct about the Default.png layouts, although left and right can be the same image if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, #%£* all apps that don't conform to the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

About Interface Orientation, I have not tested that yet. But if I imagine the iPad in normal portrait position (being the exit button at the bottom)

**I would think that Default-LandscapeLeft is iPad turned counter-clockwise while Default-LandscapeRight is clockwise.**

Unless you have a clock which is turning backwards... :-)

Cheers